How to do certifcate login in windows without the use of smart card by using LSALOGONUSER?
At the starting phase I just want to fetch the certificates from personal user store and try to authenticate the user using LSALOGONUSER. Here is the good reference LINK on how you can setup this.  Below is the code for reference. Later I need to figure out a way on how to fetch the certificates from user store as I would be integrating in a windows credential provider and credential provider won't have access to user certificate store before login.
Getting this error in the below code :
    Status: 0x0000052E/ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE (The user name or password is incorrect.)  
    
    
       #include <stdio.h>  
       #include <tchar.h>  
       #include <windows.h>  
       #include <Ntsecapi.h>  
       #include <iostream>  
       #include <intsafe.h>  
       #include <WinCred.h>  
       #include <winbase.h>  
         
       #pragma comment(lib, "Crypt32")  
         
       #define NEGOSSP_NAME_A  "Negotiate"  
         
         
       #ifndef STATUS_SUCCESS  
       #define STATUS_SUCCESS  ((NTSTATUS)0x00000000L)  
       #endif  
       #include <vcruntime_exception.h>  
         
       #pragma comment(lib, "Secur32.lib")  
         
       using namespace std;  
         
       // 1-Byte packing for this structure  
       #pragma pack(push, KerbCspInfo, 1)  
       typedef struct _KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO {  
           DWORD dwCspInfoLen;  
           DWORD MessageType;  
           union {  
               PVOID   ContextInformation;  
               ULONG64 SpaceHolderForWow64;  
           };  
           DWORD flags;  
           DWORD KeySpec;  
           ULONG nCardNameOffset;  
           ULONG nReaderNameOffset;  
           ULONG nContainerNameOffset;  
           ULONG nCSPNameOffset;  
           TCHAR bBuffer[sizeof(DWORD)];  
       } KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO, * PKERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO;  
       #pragma pack(pop, KerbCspInfo)  
         
         
         
       HRESULT UnicodeStringInitWithString(  
           _In_ PWSTR pwz,  
           _Out_ UNICODE_STRING* pus  
       )  
       {  
           HRESULT hr;  
           if (pwz)  
           {  
               size_t lenString = wcslen(pwz);  
               USHORT usCharCount;  
               hr = SizeTToUShort(lenString, &usCharCount);  
               if (SUCCEEDED(hr))  
               {  
                   USHORT usSize;  
                   hr = SizeTToUShort(sizeof(wchar_t), &usSize);  
                   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))  
                   {  
                       hr = UShortMult(usCharCount, usSize, &(pus->Length)); // Explicitly NOT including NULL terminator  
                       if (SUCCEEDED(hr))  
                       {  
                           pus->MaximumLength = pus->Length;  
                           pus->Buffer = pwz;  
                           hr = S_OK;  
                       }  
                       else  
                       {  
                           hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_ARITHMETIC_OVERFLOW);  
                       }  
                   }  
               }  
           }  
           else  
           {  
               hr = E_INVALIDARG;  
           }  
           return hr;  
       }  
         
       static void _UnicodeStringPackedUnicodeStringCopy(  
           __in const UNICODE_STRING& rus,  
           __in PWSTR pwzBuffer,  
           __out UNICODE_STRING* pus  
       )  
       {  
           pus->Length = rus.Length;  
           pus->MaximumLength = rus.Length;  
           pus->Buffer = pwzBuffer;  
         
           std::CopyMemory(pus->Buffer, rus.Buffer, pus->Length);  
       }  
         
       // Set the SeTcbPrivilege of the current process  
       BOOL SetSeTcbPrivilege()  
       {  
           TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;  
           LUID luid;  
           HANDLE hProcessToken;  
           int x;  
         
           if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),  
               TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,  
               &hProcessToken))  
           {  
               _tprintf(_T("OpenProcessToken failed with error 0x%.8X\n"), GetLastError());  
               cin >> x;  
               return FALSE;  
           }  
         
           if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(  
               NULL,  
               SE_TCB_NAME,  
               &luid))  
           {  
               _tprintf(_T("LookupPrivilegeValue failed with error 0x%.8X\n"), GetLastError());  
               CloseHandle(hProcessToken);  
               cin >> x;  
               return FALSE;  
           }  
         
           tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;  
           tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;  
           tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;  
         
           // Enable the privilege  
           if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(  
               hProcessToken,  
               FALSE,  
               &tp,  
               sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),  
               (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL,  
               (PDWORD)NULL))  
           {  
               _tprintf(_T("AdjustTokenPrivileges failed with error 0x%.8X\n"), GetLastError());  
               CloseHandle(hProcessToken);  
               cin >> x;  
               return FALSE;  
           }  
         
         
           if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)  
           {  
               _tprintf(_T("The token does not have the privilege \"SeTcbPrivilege\". \n"));  
               CloseHandle(hProcessToken);  
               cin >> x;  
               return FALSE;  
           }  
         
           CloseHandle(hProcessToken);  
         
         
           return TRUE;  
       }  
         
       // Build the authentication data used by LsaLogonUser  
         
         
         
       BOOL ConstructAuthCertInfo(const KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON& rkiulIn,LPBYTE* ppbAuthInfo, ULONG* pulAuthInfoLen)  
       {  
           UNICODE_STRING DomainName;  
           UNICODE_STRING UserName;  
           UNICODE_STRING Password;  
           NTSTATUS Status;  
           ULONG_PTR Ptr;  
           ULONG AuthInfoLength;  
           wstring WProvName;  
           DWORD ProvSize = 0;  
           wstring containerName;  
           DWORD contSize = 0;  
           HCRYPTPROV hProv;  
           DWORD dwKeySpec;  
         
           // Fetching the certificate context from the certificate store    
           // and recieving the CSP handle for the user certificate  
           HCERTSTORE      hStoreHandle = NULL;  
           PCCERT_CONTEXT  pCertContext = NULL;  
           LPCTSTR pszStoreName = _T("MY");  
           CERT_CREDENTIAL_INFO certInfo;  
           HCRYPTHASH hHash;  
           BOOL bStatus;  
           DWORD dwHashLen = CERT_HASH_LENGTH;  
           LPWSTR szMarshaledCred = NULL;  
           HANDLE hToken;  
         
           hStoreHandle = CertOpenSystemStore(NULL, pszStoreName);  
         
           if (hStoreHandle)  
           {  
               // Since my certificate store has only one user certificate, tring to retrieve PCERT_CONTEXT for it  
               pCertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(  
                   hStoreHandle,  
                   PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING,  
                   0,  
                   CERT_FIND_ANY,  
                   NULL,  
                   NULL);  
         
               if (pCertContext)  
               {  
         
                   BOOL bFreeHandle;  
         
                   // acquire private key container to this certificate      
                   if (CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(pCertContext, CRYPT_ACQUIRE_ALLOW_NCRYPT_KEY_FLAG, NULL, &hProv, &dwKeySpec, &bFreeHandle))  
                   {  
                       cout << "The private key container handle is accessed.. "<<endl<<"The dwKeySpec Value is: "<<dwKeySpec<<endl;  
                     
         
                       //Fetching the container name where the certificate is stored  
                       if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_CONTAINER, NULL, &contSize, 0))  
                       {  
                           BYTE* contName = (BYTE*)malloc(contSize);  
                           if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_CONTAINER, contName, &contSize, 0))  
                           {  
                               containerName = wstring(contName, contName + contSize);  
                               wcout << "The container name is: " << containerName << endl;  
                           }  
                           else  
                           {  
                               cout << "Could not get the container name. Exiting.."<<endl;  
                               return FALSE;  
         
                           }  
                       }  
                       else  
                       {  
                           cout << "Could not get the container size. Exiting.."<<endl;  
                           return FALSE;  
         
                       }  
         
                       //Fetching the CSP name where the certificate is stored  
                       if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_NAME, NULL, &ProvSize, 0))  
                       {  
                           BYTE* ProvName = (BYTE*)malloc(ProvSize);  
                           if (CryptGetProvParam(hProv, PP_NAME, ProvName, &ProvSize, 0))  
                           {  
                               WProvName = wstring(ProvName, ProvName + ProvSize);  
                               wcout << "The name of the CSP is: " << WProvName << endl;  
                           }  
                           else  
                           {  
                               cout << "The CSP name could not be retrieved. Exiting.." << endl;  
                               return FALSE;  
                           }  
                       }  
                       else  
                       {  
                           cout << "The CSP name size could not be retrieved. Exiting.." << endl;  
                           return FALSE;  
                       }  
         
                    }  
                   else  
                   {  
                       cout << "Could not get the Private Key Container handle. Exiting...";  
                       return FALSE;  
                   }  
               }  
               else  
               {  
                   cout << "Could not find the user certificate in the Certificate store. Exiting.." << endl;  
                   return FALSE;  
               }  
           }  
         
         
             
           // Creating and initializing a PKERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO struct for passing as an argument to KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON struct  
           // This struct stores information regarding the CSP and container of the user certs  
         
           DWORD dwReaderLen = (DWORD)_tcslen(L"") + 1;  
           DWORD dwCardLen = (DWORD)_tcslen(L"") + 1;  
           DWORD dwProviderLen = (DWORD)_tcslen(WProvName.c_str()) + 1;  
           DWORD dwContainerLen = (DWORD)_tcslen(containerName.c_str()) + 1;  
           DWORD dwBufferSize = dwReaderLen + dwCardLen + dwProviderLen + dwContainerLen;  
         
           PKERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO CspInfo = (PKERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO)malloc(sizeof(KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO) + dwBufferSize * sizeof(TCHAR));  
           std::memset(CspInfo, 0, sizeof(KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO));  
           CspInfo->dwCspInfoLen = sizeof(KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO) + dwBufferSize * sizeof(TCHAR);  
           CspInfo->MessageType = 1;  
           CspInfo->KeySpec = dwKeySpec;  
           CspInfo->nCardNameOffset = ARRAYSIZE(CspInfo->bBuffer);  
           CspInfo->nReaderNameOffset = CspInfo->nCardNameOffset + dwCardLen;  
           CspInfo->nContainerNameOffset = CspInfo->nReaderNameOffset + dwReaderLen;  
           CspInfo->nCSPNameOffset = CspInfo->nContainerNameOffset + dwContainerLen;  
           std::memset(CspInfo->bBuffer, 0, sizeof(CspInfo->bBuffer));  
           _tcscpy_s(&CspInfo->bBuffer[CspInfo->nCardNameOffset], dwBufferSize + 4 - CspInfo->nCardNameOffset, L"");  
           _tcscpy_s(&CspInfo->bBuffer[CspInfo->nReaderNameOffset], dwBufferSize + 4 - CspInfo->nReaderNameOffset, L"");  
           _tcscpy_s(&CspInfo->bBuffer[CspInfo->nContainerNameOffset], dwBufferSize + 4 - CspInfo->nContainerNameOffset, containerName.c_str());  
           _tcscpy_s(&CspInfo->bBuffer[CspInfo->nCSPNameOffset], dwBufferSize + 4 - CspInfo->nCSPNameOffset, WProvName.c_str());  
         
         
         
         
             
           const KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON* pkilIn = &rkiulIn.Logon;  
         
           // alloc space for struct plus extra for the three strings  
           DWORD cb = sizeof(rkiulIn) +  
               pkilIn->DomainName.Length +  
               pkilIn->UserName.Length +  
               pkilIn->Pin.Length +  
               CspInfo->dwCspInfoLen;  
         
           KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON* pkiulOut = (KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON*)CoTaskMemAlloc(cb);  
         
           if (pkiulOut)  
           {  
               std::ZeroMemory(&pkiulOut->LogonId, sizeof(LUID));  
         
               //  
               // point pbBuffer at the beginning of the extra space  
               //  
               BYTE* pbBuffer = (BYTE*)pkiulOut + sizeof(*pkiulOut);  
         
               //  
               // set up the Logon structure within the KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON  
               //  
               KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON* pkilOut = &pkiulOut->Logon;  
         
               pkilOut->MessageType = pkilIn->MessageType;  
               pkilOut->Flags = pkilIn->Flags;  
         
               //  
               // copy each string,  
               // fix up appropriate buffer pointer to be offset,  
               // advance buffer pointer over copied characters in extra space  
               //  
               _UnicodeStringPackedUnicodeStringCopy(pkilIn->DomainName, (PWSTR)pbBuffer, &pkilOut->DomainName);  
               pkilOut->DomainName.Buffer = (PWSTR)(pbBuffer - (BYTE*)pkiulOut);  
               pbBuffer += pkilOut->DomainName.Length;  
         
               _UnicodeStringPackedUnicodeStringCopy(pkilIn->UserName, (PWSTR)pbBuffer, &pkilOut->UserName);  
               pkilOut->UserName.Buffer = (PWSTR)(pbBuffer - (BYTE*)pkiulOut);  
               pbBuffer += pkilOut->UserName.Length;  
         
               _UnicodeStringPackedUnicodeStringCopy(pkilIn->Pin, (PWSTR)pbBuffer, &pkilOut->Pin);  
               pkilOut->Pin.Buffer = (PWSTR)(pbBuffer - (BYTE*)pkiulOut);  
               pbBuffer += pkilOut->Pin.Length;  
         
               pkilOut->CspData = (PUCHAR)(pbBuffer - (BYTE*)pkiulOut);  
               pkilOut->CspDataLength = CspInfo->dwCspInfoLen;  
         
               std::memcpy(pbBuffer,CspInfo, CspInfo->dwCspInfoLen);  
         
         
         
         
               *ppbAuthInfo = (BYTE*)pkilOut;  
               *pulAuthInfoLen = cb;  
                 
               return TRUE;  
           }  
       }  
           
         
         
       int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])  
       {  
           NTSTATUS nStatus;  
           CHAR szProcName[] = "LsaTestLogonProcess";  
           CHAR szPackageName[] = NEGOSSP_NAME_A;  
           CHAR szOriginName[] = "LsaSmartCardLogonTest";  
           LSA_STRING lsaProcName = { strlen(szProcName), strlen(szProcName) + 1, szProcName };  
           LSA_STRING lsaPackageName = { strlen(szPackageName), strlen(szPackageName) + 1, szPackageName };  
           LSA_STRING lsaOriginName = { strlen(szOriginName), strlen(szOriginName) + 1, szOriginName };  
           HANDLE lsaHandle;  
           ULONG ulAuthPackage;  
           LPBYTE pbAuthInfo = NULL;  
           ULONG  ulAuthInfoLen = 0;  
           LSA_OPERATIONAL_MODE dummy;  
           TOKEN_SOURCE tokenSource;  
           LPVOID pProfileBuffer = NULL;  
           ULONG ulProfileBufferLen = 0;  
           LUID logonId;  
           HANDLE hLogonToken;  
           QUOTA_LIMITS quotas;  
           NTSTATUS subStatus;  
           HANDLE hToken = NULL;  
         
         
         
           int x;  
           wchar_t doman[] = L"TECNICS";  
           wchar_t usernme[] = L"";  
           wchar_t pn[] = L"";  
           PWSTR domain = doman;  
           PWSTR username = usernme;  
           PWSTR pin = pn;  
         
         
           //Certificate Based Auth  
           KERB_CERTIFICATE_UNLOCK_LOGON ckiul;  
           KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON* ckil = &ckiul.Logon;  
         
           ckil->MessageType = KerbCertificateLogon;  
           ckil->Flags = 2;  
         
           // Converting Domain Name to Unicode Format  
           UnicodeStringInitWithString(domain, &ckil->DomainName);  
         
           // Passing empty UserName as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/ns-ntsecapi-kerb_certificate_logon  
           UnicodeStringInitWithString(username, &ckil->UserName);  
         
           // Passing empty PIN since no PIN asked during enrollment  
           UnicodeStringInitWithString(pin, &ckil->Pin);  
           //End  
         
         
         
         
           if (!SetSeTcbPrivilege())  
           {  
               cin >> x;  
               return 0;  
           }  
         
          
           std::memcpy(tokenSource.SourceName, "LsaTest", 8);  
           AllocateLocallyUniqueId(&tokenSource.SourceIdentifier);  
         
           nStatus = LsaRegisterLogonProcess(&lsaProcName,  
               &lsaHandle,  
               &dummy);  
           if (nStatus == STATUS_SUCCESS)  
           {  
               nStatus = LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage(lsaHandle,  
                   &lsaPackageName,  
                   &ulAuthPackage);  
               if (nStatus == STATUS_SUCCESS)  
               {  
         
                   if (!ConstructAuthCertInfo(ckiul, &pbAuthInfo, &ulAuthInfoLen))  
                   {  
                       cout << "Could not serialize the authentication data. Exiting...";  
                       cin >> x;  
                       return 0;  
                   }  
         
                   nStatus = LsaLogonUser(lsaHandle,  
                       &lsaOriginName,  
                       Interactive,  
                       ulAuthPackage,  
                       pbAuthInfo,  
                       ulAuthInfoLen,  
                       NULL,  
                       &tokenSource,  
                       &pProfileBuffer,  
                       &ulProfileBufferLen,  
                       &logonId,  
                       &hLogonToken,  
                       &quotas,  
                       &subStatus);  
                   if (nStatus == STATUS_SUCCESS)  
                   {  
                       if (pProfileBuffer)  
                           LsaFreeReturnBuffer(pProfileBuffer);  
         
                       _tprintf(_T("User logged on successfully!!\n"));  
                       cin >> x;  
                       CloseHandle(hLogonToken);  
                   }  
                   else  
                   {  
                       _tprintf(_T("LsaLogonUser failed with error 0x%.8X. SubStatus = 0x%.8X\n"), LsaNtStatusToWinError(nStatus), LsaNtStatusToWinError(subStatus));  
                       cin >> x;  
                   }  
         
         
                   HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbAuthInfo);  
               }  
               else  
               {  
                   _tprintf(_T("LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage failed with error 0x%.8X\n"), LsaNtStatusToWinError(nStatus));  
                   cin >> x;  
               }  
         
               LsaDeregisterLogonProcess(lsaHandle);  
           }  
           else  
           {  
               _tprintf(_T("LsaRegisterLogonProcess failed with error 0x%.8X\n"), LsaNtStatusToWinError(nStatus));  
               cin >> x;  
           }  
         
           return 0;  
       }


at first what you try do  integrating in a windows credential provider is senseless - simply question - how is user related to logon process ? what information it bring ? in case private key on smart card - user bring smart card. but in case private key in file - anybody can login in this case. if file was in user store - you need first login for access this store.. and all code is wrong too. for do certificate logon need encode cerificate hash in user name ( look for CertCredential )

KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON also works helps serializing data, for now i just want to get a certificate and then authenticate with the help of this ceritifcate through LSALOGONUSER. After this i will need to figure out on where to actually store the certificate but i don't want to use the smartcard. Maybe i can use some cloud endpoint if it is possible @RbMm

Again - what you try doing is absolute senseless and wrong. And for use certificate need use simply username ( encoded certificate hash) + password ( empty)

Could you explain a bit more. Do you have any links or reference where LSALOGONUSER function could be used without using KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON serialization?

You could see this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869313/how-to-write-a-ksp-to-hook-up-into-kerb-certificate-logon) which i have written my code from. Any other help would be appreciated @RbMm

again - all what you try do is senseless and wrong. user bring private key ? no. so how you really authenticate user if use private key from file ? this will be work (or not work) for any user. and if you want use cert - i already in 3-rd time say - encode cert hash in user name. and you want write own ksp too ?! for what

I just have a question how encoded certificate would be used in LSALOGONUSER function. This function is used for windows certificate authentication. I haven't seen any example doing that. Could you provide some useful links or have any working example? @RbMm

i already say you in 4 time - encode certificate hash in username - you not listen ?

I got it, in username encoded certificate hash should be used . But would i need to use it with KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON structure or need to use different structure as provided by you using _CRED_MARSHAL_TYPE as given by you above. And does LSALOGONUSER function support this structure @RbMm

simply KERB_INTERACTIVE_LOGON must be used

I created a smart logon template certificate and created the certificate encoded hash(created base64 encoded as well as hexadecimal)using this code (https://codeshare.io/MkoQXe) and my LSALOGONUSER code is this (https://codeshare.io/ONXwz7) . Getting this error LsaLogonUser failed: c000006d @RbMm

Any help would be appreciated @RbMm

Write me to email from my profile, or give your contact
